# Application and Packet layer information available to server when request sent through common gateway

Tags: java, http, ip-address, packet

When 2 machines connected to the same WIFI network send HTTP requests to a server, is the server able to differentiate between the two requests? Is there any information from which the server can come to know that the 2 requests have come from 2 different machines? As far as i understand the source IP address is not available in HTTP request. The server software extracts if from the ip packet and assigns to the variable **REMOT_ADDR**.
The FROM : IP Address sent to the server will be that of the common gateway. So the server will send the request back to the gateway. How does the gateway then forward the response back to the respective machines? If possible, please give some implementation details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 is the server able to differentiate between the two requests?
```

**No** because your wifi router acts as mediator between your network and the outer Internet. All the computers connected to your wifi network can talk to the outer network via this router only. So the http server thinks that it is talking to your wifi router.

So, in this secnerio it is the responsibility of your router to handle and differentiate between the requests coming from different computer in you network. For this you wifi router keeps a `table` which contains all the ip addresses of your computers.

So the outer http server can see only the ip address of your router and when the http server sends the response back the wifi router checks the header and decides from which of your computer the request was sent. This is done by looking in the same table which the router used earlier. After finding the correct computer the router sends the response to it.
This is called the **Network Address Translation** or `NAT`. This whole process is completely transparent to you and the http server. Your local users don't have to worry about how is this all done.

The most common reason `why NAT is used` is because your local computer don't have `static ip addresses`.

```
 Is there any information from which the server can come to know that the 2 requests have come from 2 different machines?
```

The http server can never know to which computer in your network it is talking to in terms of `low level requests and response` but at the `application level` http server can use `cookies` to know more about the actual client.

**How NAT works**

In a very simple setup the router maintains a table of ip address mappings.

In that table all the local ip addresses are mapped to a set of global ip addresses by the router.

Now when a local system sends a request to outer servers your router checks the NAT mapping table and chooses the mapped global address for the current local address.
Then the router **modifies the header of the request and sets the source address of the packet as the mapped global ip**. This way the **http server sees only this global ip** address.

When the server sends the response back, the router again checks the NAT mapping table and chooses the ip mapped to the destination of the response sent by the server, and **again modifies the header and changes the destination to the correct local ip of the system**.

**But** this method has some issues like only one local ip can be mapped to only one global ip. This limits the number of connections that can be made by one global ip.

To fix this issue, the port addresses are also included in the NAT mapping table. Now the same global ip can be used by multiple local systems because this time the pair of ip and port can varry in a very large range.

**But the original source ports are also hidden from the http server.** The source port numbers of your private systems are replaced by one of the 1024-65536 numbers by the NAT table. So there is no way for http server to know through which port your private computer made the request.

Also these source port numbers are randomly choosen by the OS from 1024-65536 values, when your browser asks the system to provide a port number. Because of randomly choosen port numbers two local system can use same ports which can create conflict. So to fix this issue the NAT software chooses a new number for each system.

This junk port number(**instead of the original source**) is sent to the server and the server can see it and also can extract it. So for example if you have used servlets on your server, you will be able to get the client port(in case of static ip) or the last proxy through which request was made by this method request.getRemotePort() in any of your servlets for any httprequest

Comment: " This is done by looking in the same table which the router used earlier." -  What information does the router store in the table that it can use to know which response to send to which machine. Because when the Server sends back the response to the Router the Network Layer for both the responses will contain the destination IP Address as the Router's address. So there must be some information in the response that is different for the reponses which the Router can use to look up the table. What is that? Is it port number like Arun Taylor mentioned in his comments?

Comment: @Ashwin: See my updated answer for the informaton stored in NAT table. Vasically it is the combination of ip and port number.

Comment: "To fix this issue, the port addresses are also included in the NAT mapping table" - this is what I am interested in. So, is this port number included in the modified request sent by the router to the external server? What I want to know is that can the external server see this Port number any where in the network layer packet?

Comment: Source ports are also hidden from the http server. The source port numbers of your private systems are replaced by one of the 1024-65536 numbers by the NAT table. So there is no way for http server to know through which port your private computer made the request. Also these source port numbers are randomly choosen by the OS from 1024-65536 values, when your browser asks the system to provide a port number. Because of randomly choosen port numbers two local system can use same ports which can create conflict. So to fix this issue the NAT software chooses a new number for the each system.

Comment: The whole point of me asking this question is because I want to know if the destination server will be able to differentiate between the 2 requests(be it using the original ports or replaced junk ports). You are saying that the NAT table contains 1 more column for junk port number vs internal ip address right? So, it should be sending this junk port no to the server right? Actually I want to extract this information in my server(the layer 3 packet information). So, I want to know if this junk port no will be present in the request that reaches the destination server

Comment: Exactly, this junk port number is sent to the server and the server can see it and also can extract it. So for example if you have used servlets on your server, you will be able to get the client port(in case of static ip) or the last proxy through which request was made by this method `request.getRemotePort()` in any of your servlets for any httprequest.

Comment: Ok. Thanks that is what I was looking for in the answer. Can you please add this details to the answer. I will then accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The WiFi router as part of doing Network Address Translation(NAT) maintains state information for connections originating from private IP addresses.

Think of the router as something like a proxy implemented at a lower level in the network stack.

The router sends requests on behalf of clients after changing the source IP and ethernet addresses, and if the clients are waiting for a response, then there will be a connection maintained by the router with the server for each of the client to receive a response on.

The only way a server can tell apart which request belongs to which client is by looking at the HTTP header. The source IP address or hostname is available in the header, but it will be the same for both clients.  One of the ways for a server to determine which request belongs to which client is to have the server use cookies to embed the notion of a session or to identify a user.  As part of a request from a client, the cookie will always be present in the HTTP header if it is set.  The server has to look for the cookie and establish who the user is.  If the user can use multiple browsers concurrently, e.g. firefox and chrome, then the server needs not only the information about the user, but also another piece of data to keep track of user's sessions.

Also, one cannot always rely on the IP address being static. It is quite common for IP address to keep changing if the browser happens to be on a smartphone and user happens to be moving, e.g. in a train.  As the smartphone connects with different cell towers, the IP address will change and the server still has to maintain the notion that the user still has a valid session.

Comment: You said that the two requests are identical to the server except might be the cookies. But NAT router while forwarding back the response has to have some information at the network layer right. So if the network layer response for both the requests remains same how does the NAT router decide to which machine to forward to? What do you mean by a connection is maintained by the server?

Comment: I said, "connection maintained by the router to the server". The router knows which private IP address initiated the request and how it is mapping or doing a NAT to the public server. Another way to think of the router is a N-way switch where it connects a private IP address+port number to a public IP address+port number,one-to-one.  For multiple public connections initiated by the router, the source IP address will be the same, but the source port numbers will all be different.

Comment: Is this port number added n network layer packet before forwarding the request to the server?